# jQuery attr error

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

what's the matter with this code? is it the .get that will not work with the .removeAttr? Thanks

```
var current = 0;
$("div#choice")[current].removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is your HTML?  What isn't working?

Comment: It's worth nothing that the `foo[0]` syntax on non-arrays is equivalent to `foo.0`, i.e., it's retrieving an object property called "0".

Comment: It's the same for Arrays, though `foo.0` isn't valid syntax in either case.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do this:

```
$("div#choice").removeAttr("style");
```

Since you are using an ID, your selector will only match one item anyway.

If you were matching multiple elements, you could do:

```
$("div.choice:first").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: OK, I thought it was something like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`removeAttr` is a jQuery method, not a native DOM method.

```
$("div#choice").eq(current).removeAttr("style");
```

You can fetch by index using the [`eq()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, which will give you the element wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: Not sure that "current" is in there for anyways if he's grabbed something with an ID. I'm guessing the problems go deeper.

Comment: @Sinetheta: Yes good point, there should only be one element with that ID. I'm guessing this was just an example and not actual code. The cause of the error is the point of my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help. the eq() was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).parent("td").next("." + classProductTotal).text("$" + price * quantity);
      ProductManager.updatePoduct(id, quantity);

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please fully explain your answer. There is insufficient detail for this to be a high quality answer.